# How to "order by" using has_many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I have two tables with a join table between them:

Parent: Pages 
Child:  Things
Join:   Grids

In my models they are set up with a many to many relationship (has_many through):

```
   class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :books
      has_many :grids
      has_many :things, :through => :grids
    end


class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :grids
      has_many :pages, :through => :grids
    end

    class Grid < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :page
      belongs_to :thing
    end
```

Now I want to be able to sort "things" using an ordering id from grid, called `number`, how can I do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: your definition of the Thing model is missing

Comment: Apologies.. it's the relationship between page and things, not the book, I fixed it in the original post : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the ":include(s)" option in your find method, and then "order_by()" ...

you would use something like this:

```
Thing.where(...some condition or all..., :include => :grid ).order_by(grid.number)
```

See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: And is that `...order_by(grid.number)` valid? What is that `grid` in that context? Should it be `...order_by('grid.number')`?

Comment: Thanks! - It worked except it's  ".order(grids.number)"  Also great links, just what I've been looking for ..